# Как вывести имена из текстового документа c помощью Python?

Tags: python

Есть текстовый документ, пример:

```
Dave Martin

173 Main St., Springfield RI 55924

davemartin@bogusemail.com

Charles Harris

969 High St., Atlantis VA 34075

charlesharris@bogusemail.com
```

Вот это содержится в документе .txt, как мне с помощью Python извлечь нужную мне информацию?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Извлечь = ***? Что это значит? Уточните вашу проблему. На каком этапе возникает проблема? Вы не можете получить путь к файлу? Вы не можете его прочитать? В чём проблема? Отредактируйте вопрос, указав в нём КОРРЕКТНУЮ и ЧЁТКО сформулированную проблему.

Comment: Имелось ввиду, что мне нужно вывести в пайтоне имена, взятые из текстового документа.
Файл я прочитал с помощью with open, мне не понятно как сделать так, что бы пайтон сам находил имена, находящиеся в документе.

Comment: Для того чтобы Python как Вы говорите сам находил имена,  нужно написать ему инструкции (код). Приведите здесь фрагмент кода и Вам постараются помочь .

Comment: Я понимал, что надо написать код :)
с помощью
`with open("people.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:`
в файле содержатся строки в виде:
имя фамилия
почтовый адрес
адрес проживания
Мне нужно, что бы питон из .txt файла вывел только имена, находящиеся в файле. 
Пример:
Charles Harris
800-555-5669
969 High St., Atlantis VA 34075
charlesharris@bogusemail.com

Eric Williams
560-555-5153
806 1st St., Faketown AK 86847
laurawilliams@bogusemail.com
`какой-то код`
Питон выводит мне 
"Charles Harris
Eric Williams"

Comment: Аа, так вам морфологический анализатор нужен! Например, `pymorphy` или `pymorphy2` посмотрите. Сам не работал с ними, так что без комментариев. Или другой какой поискать можете, если тут не посоветуют.

Comment: ну, выведите каждую третью строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас так и будут обстоять дела с вашим файлом и сохранится закономерность, то можно увидеть, что только строки с именами содержат только буквы. Если это так, то можно собирать их по этому принципу

```py
result = []

with open("people.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if "".join(line.split()).isalpha():
            result.append(line.strip())

print(result)
```

Вывод

```
['Dave Martin', 'Charles Harris']
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Akamichy на здоровье)